# How does an ahead-of-time compiler determine how far to go with optimization?

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-construction

Optimization in modern compilers is getting better and better with basic optimizations like constant folding to utilizing SIMD instructions. However, I wonder how far these kind of optimizations should be taken and how this decision is made by compilers nowadays.

Let's look at an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static double naive_sin(double n) {
    return n - n*n*n / 6.0 + n*n*n*n*n / 120.0 + n*n*n*n*n*n*n / 5040.0;
}

int main() {
    printf("%f\n", naive_sin(1.0));

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling this with GCC with `-O3`, it can be observed that the resulting floating point number is calculated by the compiler and stored in the source code. Optimizing further than that is obviously not possible.

Now, let's look at a second example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double start = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        start += 1.0;
    }

    printf("%f\n", start);

    return 0;
}
```

With the result of the first example in mind, one could expect the compiler to apply similar optimization and produce the constant `100.0` in the resulting machine code. However, when looking at the output, it turns out that the loop is still there!

Obviously this kind of optimization is not always possible. Let's say you were writing a program that calculates pi to a million places. Such a program requires no user input, so theoretically the result could be hardcoded into the machine code by the compiler. Of course this is not a good idea, because the compiler will take much longer to internally evaluate a program like that as opposed to just running the less optimized version.

Still, what makes the compiler decide to not optimize the loop in this case? Are there languages/compilers that optimize this kind of code or is there something preventing this? Is it perhaps related to the concept of not being able to predict if a program is ever going to end?

Comment: "How does an ahead-of-time compiler determine how far to go with optimization?" - it looks at the command line flags :))

Comment: "Not being able to predict if a program is ever going to end" is (FYI) called the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).  Note that compilers can and do unroll some loops, so compilers can prove in *some* cases that a loop will terminate.

Comment: It is a non-issue.  AOT tackles a *graph* of code, it doesn't actually *execute* the code.  Programmers don't write infinitely nested functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really just a question of which optimizations are enabled, and what optimizations are actually available in your compiler. Some optimizations, like function inlining and constant propagation, are basically universally available and relatively easy to implement. So, the majority of compilers will optimize the first program with most optimization settings.

The second program requires loop analysis and loop elimination to optimize, which is much trickier to do. A compiler probably *could* optimize the second program, but your compiler most likely doesn't have the mechanisms for optimizing such a loop (proving the correctness of float optimizations is often a lot trickier than proving the correctness of integer optimizations). Note that my version of GCC does optimize the loop if `start` is declared as an `int`.